# Easy and Quick Layout for Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I really come from Web Development and I rarely do anything with Swing. However, today I am trying to achieve some simple GUI in Swing, but I'm having trouble because I don't have the time (...yeah, maybe it's rather the lack of interest because I don't see the need to learn it) on understanding GridLayout, GridBagLayout and others in deep...

So, I just want something like the following (each X is a component):

```
X X X X
   X
```

And all be centered, which is already working. What I don't manage to do is to just find a Layout where I can simply arrange X Components in one row, and then only one in the next, no special alignment needs there...

What's the easiest / cleanest way of getting such a layout with Swing?

Comment: You don't need to find *a* layout manager. It's normal to nest layouts. The rows can each have their own layout manager, and then have a layout manager than handles placing the rows themselves.

Comment: You can use a vertical BoxLayout containing an horizontal BoxLayout for the first row.

Comment: Or two `FlowLayout` panels in a `GridLayout(2, 1)`.

Comment: Use containers like JPanel/JScrollPane which can have their own layouts. Try NetBeans with its GUI editor. Faster, and the generated code is slim as can be.

Comment: Well, I tried with both Approaches. However, I then need the elements in the first Row to be "bottom-aligned" and the second row to be "top-aligned". It's just too complex to get this done right... :(

Comment: Try using [MiG Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/) ?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
private static JPanel createPanel() {
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    final JPanel firstRowPanel = new JPanel();
    firstRowPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(firstRowPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    firstRowPanel.add(new JLabel("X"));
    firstRowPanel.add(new JLabel("X"));
    firstRowPanel.add(new JLabel("X"));
    firstRowPanel.add(new JLabel("X"));

    final JPanel secondRowPanel = new JPanel();
    secondRowPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(secondRowPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    secondRowPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    secondRowPanel.add(new JLabel("X"));
    secondRowPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

    panel.add(firstRowPanel);
    panel.add(secondRowPanel);
    return panel;
}
```